# Extending functionality of a Python library class which is part of a structure

Tags: python, pyqt, can-bus

I am working with the Python [canmatrix library](https://github.com/ebroecker/canmatrix) (well, presently my [Python3 fork](https://github.com/altendky/canmatrix)) which provides a set of classes for an in-memory description of CAN network messages as well as scripts for importing and exporting to and from on-disk representations (various standard CAN description file formats).

I am writing a PyQt application using the canmatrix library and would like to add some minor additional functionality to the bottom level `Signal` class.  Note that a `CanMatrix` organizes it's member `Frame`s which in turn organize it's member `Signal`s.  The whole structure is created by an import script which reads a file.  I would like to retain the import script and sub-member finder functions of each layer but add an extra 'value' member to the `Signal` class as well as getters/setters that can trigger Qt signals (not related to the canmatrix `Signal` objects).

It seems that standard inheritance approaches would require me to subclass every class in the library and override every function which creates the library `Signal` to use mine instead.  Ditto for the import functions.  This just seems horribly excessive to add non-intrusive functionality to a library.

I have tried inheriting and replacing the library class with my inherited one (with and without the pass-through constructor) but the import still creates library classes, not mine.  I forget if I copied this from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028797/228539) or not, but it's the same structure as referenced there.

```
class Signal(QObject, canmatrix.Signal):
    _my_signal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        canmatrix.Signal.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # TODO: what about QObject
        print('boo')

    def connect(self, target):
        self._my_signal.connect(target)

    def set_value(self, value):
        self._my_value = value
        self._my_signal.emit(value)

canmatrix.Signal = Signal
print('overwritten')
```

**Is there a direct error in my attempt here?**

**Am I doing this all wrong and need to go find some (other) design pattern?**

My next attempt involved shadowing each instance of the library class.  For any instance of the library class that I want to add the functionality to I must construct one of my objects which will associate itself with the library-class object.  Then, with an extra layer, I can get from either object to the other.

```
class Signal(QObject):
    _my_signal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, signal):
        signal.signal = self
        self.signal = signal
        # TODO: what about QObject parameters
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.value = None

    def connect(self, target):
        self._my_signal.connect(target)

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self._my_signal.emit(value)
```

The extra layer is annoying (`library_signal.signal.set_value()` rather than `library_signal.set_value()`) and the mutual references seem like they may keep both objects from ever getting cleaned up.

This does run and function, but I suspect there's still a better way.